# 15amp breaker for 9 dual outlets?

Tags: electrical-panel

I tried using my pressure washer in my back patio and it quickly tripped my gfci outlet and I had to reset the breaker. I then noticed that all 4 exterior, 3 garage, and two laundry room outlets were all tied in together. (Laundry room ones not for washer or dryer). Is this safe? I'm still under warranty with the builder, and have an electrician coming out. What can I do to tell them on how to resolve, as I'm sure they won't want to fix??

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need a little more information before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

If this were a commercial installation you'd need to provision 180VA per yoke, or **ten duplex receptacles** per 1800W (15A) circuit.  However in residential, there is no limit.

However that won't help.  Essentially what you're saying is you want your outlets divided into enough circuits that you never get an overload trip.  That's a tall order.  You're talking one circuit per receptacle.  I'm willing to do that in a kitchen or bathroom, but all over the house? This rapidly reaches a point of diminishing returns, *and it doesn't solve the underlying problem*.

### Understanding how to use electricity

It wouldn't matter if you had 2000 receptacles on a circuit.  **Whether it blows or not depends on what *loads are in use***, what *current* each load individually draws, and what the total current is. 3 cell phone chargers, 9 LED lights and a table saw, that'll be fine.  A table saw and a dust collector, *not gonna happen*.

### Overload trip

There are two possibilities here.  One is that your pressure washer, combined with the other loads on that circuit, is drawing more than 15 amps.  You will have to research that yourself, but the general concept is that you should learn what each of your loads draws.  It has a nameplate which states rated current, or you can get a gadget called a "Kill-a-Watt" which will tell you what it actually draws real-time.

### GFCI trip

The other possibility is that the appliance has a ground fault.  This is, after all, an appliance that involves water.   Somewhere you have a GFCI device which will tell you.  There is a fair chance it is not at the outdoor socket location, as putting GFCI device outdoors tends to be really hard on them, and they can protect the entire circuit from elsewhere.  Anyway, if it is a device that ONLY does GFCI - a GFCI receptacle, switch or deadfront - then you know it was a GFCI trip.  However if it was a GFCI breaker, you need to get its documentation and follow its procedure for determining whether the trip was a ground fault or overload trip.  Most of them make it rather easy.

If it indicates a GFCI trip, move the appliance onto a different GFCI circuit, such as the bathroom or kitchen.  If you don't want to operate the appliance there, get a 3-prong extension cord plugged in there.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can have a lot of receptacles on one 15A or 20A breaker. There are some exceptions, mostly relating to kitchens & bathrooms.

Builders tend to do what is cheapest - and that means as few circuits as possible, particularly if the routing of the cabling makes sense. In the case of the listed receptacles - exterior, garage, laundry room - what they all have in common is that they need GFCI protection. Most other receptacles, except for kitchens & bathrooms, do **not** need GFCI.

The only real concern is whether the trip was due to improper installation or simply due to "too much water". An exterior receptacle should be *weather resistant* with an *in-use cover*. If it is the right type and things are OK after they dry out then there is nothing to complain to the builder about. If the receptacle is not weather resistant (this is a *type* of receptacle, not just a description) or does not have an in-use cover, then that should be fixed.

Comment: While it is true that builders will try to cut costs whenever possible (and safe) there are various international, national and municipal codes that impose dedicated circuits on some outlets, based on their function. A dishwasher must have its own dedicated circuit. Generally, every common fixed appliance has its own dedicated outlet. That said, if I built my own house, I would have a dedicated circuit for outdoor outlets, and the garage/shop would probably have its own board with each outlet on a separate circuit. I feel sorry for the OP if they have so many outlets on the same circuit

Comment: It is pretty clear in this case that the receptacles do *not* include any kitchen or bathroom requirements or even the laundry room "separate for washer & dryer". The builder took all the **other** GFCI and put them together to save on an extra GFCI breaker or two.